# Home page after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app while refreshing on the pages that require being loggedIn it takes me to homepage. Information that someone is loggedIn stored in state which gets updated on base of value of auth true/false (which is stored in sessionstorage). How can I force react to first change state (its default is false) before rendering component?

````
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [user, setUser] = useState("temp");

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials=true;
  useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/check")
    .then((response)=>{
      sessionStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(response.data["Authorized"]));
    });
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("auth")==="true"){
      setLoggedIn(true)
    }else{
      setLoggedIn(false)
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      {loggedIn ? <LoggedInNavbar user={user}  /> : <Navbar/>}
      <AnimatePresence>
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route 
            path="/" 
            element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route 
            path="/logowanie/:state" 
            element={loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/"/> : <LogIn/>}/>
          <Route 
            path="/rejestracja" 
            element={loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/"/> : <SignUp/>}/>
          <Route 
            path="/regulamin" 
            element={<Rules/>}/>
          <Route 
            path="/dashboard/:username" 
            element={loggedIn ? <Dashboard  user={user}/> : <Navigate to="/"/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  )
}```
````

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Add a loading state and don't render your routes until the auth status is known. Or initialize your state with `sessionStorage.getItem("auth")` instead of `false`. Your effect runs on every render so it's unclear which path you want to take.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/check")
    .then((response)=>{
      sessionStorage.setItem('auth', 
      JSON.stringify(response.data["Authorized"]));
    });
    
    // this part of code is executed BEFORE the Axios response
    // Axios.get is async and the `if` condition does not wait for
    // Axios response to be processed.
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("auth")==="true"){
      setLoggedIn(true)
    }else{
      setLoggedIn(false)
    }
    })
```

The correct use of this should like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/check")
    .then((response)=>{
      sessionStorage.setItem('auth', 
      JSON.stringify(response.data["Authorized"]));
      if(response.data["Authorized"])){
        setLoggedIn(true)
      }else{
        setLoggedIn(false)
      }
    });
    }, []) // <-- attention, you have to give dependency list,
    // so this useEffect is used only on first render.
```

Another is the main pillar of your problem:

```
         <Route 
            path="/dashboard/:username" 
            element={loggedIn ? <Dashboard  user={user}/> : <Navigate to="/"/>}/>
```

Don't redirect user, simply render the  `Home` path, if the user is not logged in.

```
         <Route 
            path="/dashboard/:username" 
            element={loggedIn ? <Dashboard  user={user}/> : <Home />}/>
```

With this logic, you will use the `loggedIn` state the proper way: as soon as React will get `true` in `loggedIn` state, user will get the Dashboard element. (Or you can take him directly to `LogIn` element.)
What more - as soon as user logs in, he is taken back to the path, he was previously looking for - because it stays in URL.

Comment: Could I just use your example of useEffect with dependency list of location? This way I would check if user  is loggedIn everytime that he goes to different page. Is this proper approach? Plus in this scenario, is there a need of using session storage at all?

Comment: You don't need to do this. As soon as the state of `loggedIn` state is `false`, user will receive the element from right side of the condition. And I don't use the session storage. Because, after all, client is not the side deciding the sign in state - it is server. Generally, the application is "public" for any client, you are not able to hide the code from it. If there is something secret, that are the data on the server - and there you check the login state every time, I suppose.

Comment: I do it very similarly as you, only my loggedIn state is named `[user, setUser]` - here I store some basic data about the user sent from server. This allows me to use this information in application (e.g. email, creation date, email confirmed, user rights,...) Everything is stored in `user` state.